# Rails default value for select not being set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a Comment and a Post, where the Post `has_many` Comments and the Comment `belong_to` the Post.

In the admin interface, I have a dropdown menu for selecting which post a comment belongs to.

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :text, "Comment Text" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label "Post" %><br />
    <%= f.select(:post_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Post.all, :id, :title), :include_blank => true) %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</p>
```

However, the select tag default value is not being selected, even though it says in the documentation it should automatically default to `@comment.post_id`. Any ideas why this isn't happening?

Comment: it should be `belongs_to`. Is it a typo?

Comment: What's the emitted HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Rails will only automatically use `@comment.post_id` if you just pass an Array as the second object instead of using `options_from_collection_for_select`. Here's the [relevant documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select). So if you did this, it would work fine:

```
<%= f.select(:post_id, 
             Post.all.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id] }, 
             :include_blank => true) %>
```

If you want to stick with `options_from_collection_for_select`, then you need to tell it what value to use as the selected value:

```
<%= f.select(:post_id, 
             options_from_collection_for_select(Post.all, :id, :title, @comment.post_id), 
             :include_blank => true) %>
```